# C, call main function of main.c from an header file

Tags: c

my question is pretty simple: if i have a main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "settings.h"

int main(int argc, char * agrv[])
{
    printf("Homepage");
    char choice[3];
    fgets(choice, sizeof(choice), stdin);
    if (strcmp(choice, "1") == 0)
    {
        openSettings();
    }
}
```

and a settings.h file:

```
void openSettings();
```

with settings.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "settings.h"

void openSettings()
{
    printf("Settings");
    char choice[3];
    fgets(choice, sizeof(choice), stdin);
    if (strcmp(choice, "1") == 0)
    {
        printf("something");
    }   
    else if (strcmp(choice, "1") == 0)
    {
        //return to main function (the homepage)
    }
}
```

how can i return to main function in manìin.c from settings.c?

Comment: Did you try `return`?

Comment: @dbush only "return"?

Comment: Well, the way you've written if, your `openSettings` function is *always* going to return to `main`.  In the "something" case, were you wanting it *not* to return to `main`?

Comment: You don't even need `return`. Just let the function run to completion.

Comment: Remember that [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) reads and *adds* the newline in the buffer. You might want to [remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) before using the string.

Comment: Also don't skimp on the buffer size. Don't be afraid to use larger buffers for your input.

Comment: yes, because if you mess up by typing say "12" that leaves some of it in the buffer, and there will be a mistake at the next input too.

Comment: The `//return to main function (the homepage)`  can never be executed. The code will always end by reaching the end of the function. It is like `if(1==1) { /* some code */} else if (1==1) { /* some other code returning to main function */ }  {/* default */}`, that should illustrate, why "default" is always executed. and "return to main" never.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i return to main function in [main.c] from settings.c?

In general, when a function finishes executing, control automatically returns to the caller.  You don't have to do anything special to make that happen.  (The exceptions are when the function terminates by calling a function that terminates execution of the whole program, such as `Exit()`, or when the program crashes.)  You can make function execution terminate at any point via a `return` statement, or, if the function does not need to return a value, then it's fine to allow control to reach the closing brace of the function body, at which point it returns.

If the function is declared to return a value then that value should be specified via a `return` statement.  Otherwise, `return` statements in the function must not specify any return value.